# How to use same validation control for more than one webform control

Tags: asp.net

I prompt the user to enter date. For that I have given three dropdown lists 
now I want only one required field validator to be used for the three dropdown lists for day month and year.

Answer (score 1):

Property "ControlToValidate" not allows you to set a few controls. Your should to write your own validator, by using JS for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try without giving any controller as `ControlToValidate` and giving your own `ClientValidationFunction`

```
<asp:CustomValidator id="AtLeastOneContact" runat="server"  
  ErrorMessage="Phone or Email Required" 
  Display="Dynamic"
  OnServerValidate="AtLeastOneContact_ServerValidate" 
  ClientValidationFunction="AtLeastOneContact_ClientValidate" />
```

**Client Side Validation**

```
<script type="text/vbscript" language="vbscript">
<!--
    Sub AtLeastOneContact_ClientValidate(source, args)
        'Requires that either Phone or Email is not empty

        If document.getElementById("<%= Phone.ClientID %>").value & _
           document.getElementById("<%= Email.ClientID %>").value <> "" Then
            args.IsValid = true
        Else
            args.IsValid = false
        End If
    End Sub
'-->
</script>
```

[check this for more information.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/MultiDependValidator.aspx)